# Is there an easy way to get ONLY the shipping price of a product using a shipping API, or to calculate that shipping price using the client address?

Tags: php, api, paypal

Let's start introducing myself not only as a new software developer but also as someone new to asking on StackOverflow.

So, i've built an e-commerce project on php with a shopping cart and the Paypal api, which works the way it is intended.

I'd like to add the estimated shipping price to the total price from one or any shipping company really, let's say for example, DHL, UPS, etc.

I've seen that there are multiple shipping API's out there, but i can´t find any practical tutorial online for what i have searched.

I've also seen that WordPress has an e-commerce template where the shipping price is calculated by giving away your address information [WordPress Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQdlw.png)

Is there any way to calculate the shipping price or to consume an API and get ONLY the shipping price so i can add it to my Paypal payment module?
[My way of payment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGm01.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.